# Show only ID's where latest date is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
Person  Date
p1      null
p1      05/22/2000
p1      05/21/2000
p2      08/03/2000
p2      08/02/2000
p2      08/01/2000
p3      08/20/2000
p4      null
p4      02/01/2001
```

How do I query this result where I would exclude those people `'p'` whose latest date is `NULL` like when `p1` has a `null` in its latest date, p1 should not show in the result list same with `p4`. I know that a simple `Where clause` will not work with this one as it will only remove `p1` with `null` value. I even have tried using `WHERE MAX(DATE) <> ''` but it gives me Error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference

Comment: How do you know what the latest date is, if it is `NULL`?

Comment: show an expected result for your data

Comment: You want to exclude all persons who have at least one record with a `null` date, right?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, you're right. I didn't event think of that.

Comment: @PeterAbolins yes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using sqlserver2014

Comment: I won't provide an answer, because you already have two. The approach by @Esteban-P is the way I would have gone, unless you really need the added complications of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: you can easily achieve it by using not in and sub query. Learn basics first.

Comment: @PeterAbolins, answers are quite opposite though..

Comment: @Shulz, yes, although the other answer was changed half a dozen times. Now I don't even think it addresses your original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude all persons who have at least one record with `Date = NULL`, then you could use `NOT IN`:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM yourtable 
 WHERE Person NOT IN 
         (SELECT Person 
            FROM yourtable 
           WHERE Date IS NULL
         )
```

Comment: "p1 would not show in the result list same with p4"

Comment: as far as i understood, he wants to exclude the persons entirely if there is at least one entry with Date = NULL.

Comment: @CaiusJard you're right. i removed the second part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't say for sure if that null is a late date or an early date so your request as it stands doesn't make sense. I'll have to redefine/guess what you're looking for:

"I want a list of only the person IDs who have a Date value in every single row"

Which is something simple like:

```
SELECT
  personID
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  personID
HAVING count(date) = count(*)
```

`count(date)` will not count nulls, `count(*)` will count rows with a null date because you're not specifying a particular (nullable) column to count. `count(personid)` should also work in place of `count(*)` if it makes more sense to you. In either case, you end up with a `count(date)` that is lower than `count(*)` and by stating you only want results where these two counts are equal, it means you only get those IDs who DON'T have any nulls in their rows

Interestingly, your attempt at doing this `MAX(date) <> ''` implies you believe that null and the empty string are equivalent. In SQLServer this is not true.. To test something for NULL, use `IS/ISNOT NULL`. `MAX()` will never return a null when there are non-null values in the aggregated group, neither will `MIN()`

Comment: "p1 would not show in the result list same with p4"

Comment: indeed, when I group by 'p1', `count(date)` is 2 but `count(*)` is 3, and the HAVING requires that these two values be equal.. "p1 does not show in the result list, same with p4"